# Using switch statements to fork two processes

Tags: c, linux, posix

I'm taking an intro to C course and I've become a bit stumped on the first assignment.  We've been tasked with creating a parent processes and two child processes.  All of the examples the text has shown us so far involve switch statements with one parent and one child.  I'm a bit confused about how to translate this into one parent and two child processes.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, pid, status;
    pid = fork();
    switch(pid) {
    case -1:
        /* An error has occurred */
        printf("Fork Error");
        break;
    case 0:
        /* This code is executed by the first parent */
        printf("First child process is born, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
        printf("First child parent process is %d\n", getppid());
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
            printf("First child process, iteration: %d\n", i);
        printf("First child dies quietly.\n");
        break;
    default:
        /* This code is executed by the parent process */
        printf("Parent process is born, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
        wait(&status);
        printf("Parent process dies quietly.\n");
    }
}
```

This works perfect for this one process:

```
Parent process is born, my pid is 10850
First child process is born, my pid is 10851
First child parent process is 10850
First child process, iteration: 1
First child process, iteration: 2
First child process, iteration: 3
First child process, iteration: 4
First child process, iteration: 5
First child process, iteration: 6
First child process, iteration: 7
First child process, iteration: 8
First child process, iteration: 9
First child process, iteration: 10
First child dies quietly.
Parent process dies quietly.
```

Essentially I just need to do the same thing with a second process... something like:

```
printf("Second child process is born, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
printf("Second child parent process is %d\n", getppid());
for (k=1; k<=10; k++)
    printf("Second child process, iteration: %d\n", i);
printf("Second child dies quietly.\n");
break;
```

But I'm just not sure how to get there from what I have so far.  Am I approaching this correct way?  Is there a better method I should be using?  Thanks so much.

Comment: You might want to read more about [forking](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html)

Comment: You are just using the `switch` to check the return of `fork` (you can use `if..then..else` as well). Just call `fork` twice and check both returns (e.g. two full `fork` / `switch` blocks). Then you have one-parent, two-children.

Comment: You are lacking a Linux or POSIX tag.

Comment: Is your question about using `switch` for `fork` or about how to create two children processes? I downvoted your question because its focus is unclear, and these are really two very different and independent questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general rule. When you use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) you should **always handle the *three* cases** below:

1. `fork` gave 0, you are in the *child* process
2. `fork` gave a positive `pid_t`, you are in the *parent* process
3. `fork` *failed* and gave -1

People (newbies) sometimes tend to forget the last (failure) case. But it does happen, and you might easily test that case by using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_NPROC` in your grand-parent process to lower the limit on processes, often that grand-parent process is your shell (e.g. using [`ulimit` Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) with `-u`).

Now, how to handle the three cases is a matter of coding style. You can use `switch` but you can use two `if`. Your code uses a `switch` and is right to do so.

As a general rule, most [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) can fail, and you almost always need to handle the failure case (see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (freely downloadable).

> I'm a bit confused about how to translate this into one parent and two child processes.

The `fork` system call is creating (on success) exactly *one* child process. So if you need two children, you should call it twice (and test failure on both calls) in a row. If you need one child and one grand child, you should do the second `fork` only when the first one gave 0. Of course you need to keep both (successful and positive) `pid_t` -e.g. in two variables- returned by your two calls to `fork`.

To avoid [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), every successful `fork` should later have its wait system call (e.g. [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or `wait` or [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) or `wait3`). Where you do that wait depends if you want to have both children running at the same time or not. But every successful `fork` should have a corresponding successful `wait` call.

Read also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) about `SIGCHLD` if you want to be *asynchronously* notified about child processes change - notably termination. A common way is to install a `SIGCHLD` signal handler (e.g. using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) or the old [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)) which just sets some global `volatile sigatomic_t` flag and test then clear that flag in convenient place in your code (e.g. in some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)).

NB: notice that `fork` is not about C programming (`fork` is *not* defined in the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or its predecessor [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)). It is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) and Linux thing. Windows or [z/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS) or an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) microcontroller don't have it natively, but are programmable in some standard C.

Comment: I improved my answer. If you need two children, you should do two `fork`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can put fork and switch case in loop so that it forks multiple processes, something like below:

Edit: You can remove `if` condition to call `wait` after each fork, alternately if you want to launch all children then wait for them to terminate, in each iteration you can collect pid of each child (in parent process ie in default switch case) in an array and in last iteration call waitpid in a loop(for each pid) to ensure each child process has exited

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int i, pid, status;
    int j = 0;
    int numChildren = 2;/*Change it to fork any number of children*/
    for(j = 0;j< numChildren;j++)
    {
            pid = fork();
            switch(pid) {
            case -1:
                /* An error has occurred */
                printf("Fork Error");
                break;
            case 0:
                /* This code is executed by the first parent */
                printf("First child process is born, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
                printf("First child parent process is %d\n", getppid());
                for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
                    printf("First child process, iteration: %d\n", i);
                printf("First child dies quietly.\n");
                exit(0);/*Otherwise it will fork its own child*/
                break;
            default:
                /* This code is executed by the parent process */
                printf("Parent process is born, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
                if(j == (numChildren - 1))/*You can remove this condition to wait after each fork*/
                {
                wait(&status);
                printf("Parent process dies quietly.\n");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You `wait` only once, while you should `wait` for all child processes.

Answer (score -1):

To make 2 child you call fork()2x. So call fork with 2 different variable and then wait for them both.

Comment: I think my comment is longer, perhaps a little more explanation is warranted in an answer?