# How to run multiple shell command at the same time in linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I am trying to run multiple command in ubuntu using c++ code at the same time.
I used `system()` call to run multiple command but the problem with `system()` call is it invoke only one command at a time and rest commands are in waiting.
below I wrote my sample code, may this help you to get what I am trying to do.
major thing is I want to run all these command at a time not one by one. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
main()
{   
   string command[3];
   command[0]= "ls -l";
   command[1]="ls";
   command[2]="cat main.cpp";  

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
       system(command[i].c_str());
   }   
}
```

Comment: In whatever book/etc you're learning C++ on UNIX from, find the section on `fork()`.

Comment: (more specifially, on `fork()` and `exec()` and process-management in general.

Comment: You can use `int main(){return 0;}` You are not checking the return value of `system` so you don't care if commands you run succeed or not. Might just as well not run them.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (a bit old, but freely available). You probably want (in the traditional way, like most shells do):

- perhaps catch `SIGCHLD` (set the signal handler *before* `fork`, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)...)
- call [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a new process. Be sure to check all [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44298741/841108) cases (failure with a negative returned `pid_t`, child with a 0 `pid_t`, parent with a positive `pid_t`). If you want to communicate with that process, use [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) (read about [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)...) *before* the `fork`.
- in the child process, close some useless file descriptors, then run some [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) function (or the underlying [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)) to run the needed program (e.g. `/bin/ls`)
- call (in the parent, perhaps after having got a `SIGCHLD`) [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) or [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or related functions.

This is very usual. Several chapters of [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) are explaining it better.

There is no need to use threads in your case.

However, notice that the role of `ls` and `cat` could be accomplished with various system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...), notably [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) & [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html). You might not even need to run other processes. See also [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

Perhaps (notably if you communicate with *several* processes thru several [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s) you might want to have some [*event loop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the older `select(2)`). Some libraries provide an event loop (notably all GUI widget libraries).

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options (as always):

- Use threads (C++ standard library implementation is good) to spawn multiple threads which each perform a system call then terminate. `join` on the thread list to wait for them all to terminate.
- Use the *NIX `fork` command to spawn a new process, then within each child process use `exec` to execute the desired command (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461548/how-to-pass-arguments-to-processes-created-by-fork) for an example of "getting the right string to the right child"). Parent process can use `waitpid` to determine when all children have finished running, in order to move on with the program.
- Append "&" to each of your commands, which'll tell the shell to run each one in the background (specifically, `system` will start the process in the background then return, without waiting for the result). Not tried this, don't know if it'll work. You can't then wait for the call to terminate though (thanks PSkocik).

Just pointing out - if you run those 3 specific commands at the same time, you're unlikely to be able to read the output as they'll all print text to the terminal at the same time.

If you do require reading the output from within the program (though not mentioned in your question), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix?noredirect=1&lq=1) is relevant (although it doesn't use `system`).

Comment: The last item is false. `system("something &");` will asynchronously create  a grandchild and return. You generally can't `wait` on grand children.

Comment: My opinion is that `fork` & `waitpid` is the most adequate solution, not threading.

Comment: @PSkocik Ooh, didn't know that - I'll update answer.

Comment: I disagree with `fork` messier than threads. In that particular case, it is better (and OP should *not* use threads).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you mean `fork` then `exec` the desired command?

Comment: Yes, `fork`, then `exec` the command in the child, and `wait` or `waitpid` in the parent. BTW handling `SIGCHLD` signal in parent could be useful

Comment: With `fork()`/`exec()` capturing the output from each process separately is a well established technique. As I commented above, read a chapter in a book.